# Can't get wordpress admin role to work

Tags: wordpress

In a twist of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608351/fix-wordpress-broken-database-capabilities-no-role-assigned), I am unable to log into the WP Dashboard as the admin. When I do log in, it first just treats me as a subscriber with no access to anything. I just get the black bar at the top with the name of the site on the left and my username on the right. When I try to go to sitename.com/wp-admin, then I get the message "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." after logging into the dashboard.

In the `wp_usermeta` table, the admin user (`user_id`=1) has its `wp_capabilities` meta key set to the expected `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code put in functions.php

```
function  changeUserRole (){
    $wuser_ID = 1;
    if ($wuser_ID)
        {
          $userData = get_userdata($wuser_ID);
          $role = $userData->roles[0];
          if($role != 'administrator'){
            // Add role
            $userData->add_role( 'administrator' );
          }
        }
}

add_action('init','changeUserRole');
```